# How to move UVs by a set amount of pixels?

Tags: uv-image-editor

In Blender 2.7, using the UV editor, selecting some vertices / UV islands, I was then able to use <kbd>G</kbd> (grab), followed by a number, for example <kbd>8</kbd>, to move the selected vertices / island by exactly 8 pixels.

In Blender 2.8, it seems that doing the above, the number entered does not correspond to image pixels, but instead to UV coordinates (`0.0` to `1.0`). Given a texture of size `1024`, moving the selection by `0.5` would hence effectively move it by `512` pixels.

Is there any way to do the 2.7 way in 2.8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found it myself. Here goes:

In the UV editor, open the right-hand menu via <kbd>N</kbd>, then select the `View` tab. There, check `Pixel Coordinates`. Now, coordinates will be shown in pixels and the grab/move commands will also operate on pixels.